# connect ETIMEDOUT Error while accessing a remote database even though the port 3306 is open

Tags: mysql, node.js, dialogflow-es

This is the first time I am using nodejs. I am trying to build a chatbot using dialogflow, and i am trying to access the database of my website hosted on a server. However, it is giving me an error of ETIMEDOUT, even though the port is open for user 'omkar'. I am able to access the database through my terminal on my device, by using the user 'omkar'. What could be the reason this error is encountered ? Here is my code :

```
  function connectDataBase(){
const connection=mysql.createConnection({
  host:'ip_of_my_database_server',
  user:'omkar',
  password:'my_password',
  database:'database_name'
});

return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    });
  resolve(connection);
});}


  function queryDataBase(connection){
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
  connection.query('SELECT * from auth_user',(error,results,fields)=>{
    resolve(results);
  });
});}

  function handlerRank(agent){
return connectDataBase().then(connection=>{
  return queryDataBase(connection).then(result=>{
    console.log('Printing');
    console.log(result);
    agent.add(result[0].first_name);
    connection.end();
  });
});}
```

Edit 1:

I have checked whether my mysql database is accessible remotely or not. Port 3306 is accessible for an external client. Also, the user ‘omkar’ has appropriate permissions for viewing and updating the database.

I am using the dialogflow inline editor, in which the above code is written.

Comment: could you typo correct you question please, and break it down in steps stating what is the setup and things you already checked.

Comment: This issue has been reported here on SO but with no definitive solution. I would suggest using the hostname of the db sever or other tricks suggested on this discussion: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1474

Comment: `ETIMEDOUT` is a networking-stack (TCP/IP) error message. It means the machine running your mysql client (nodejs program in your case) could not get through to the database machine at all. It has nothing to do with the username. `ETIMEDOUT` means there's a firewall between the two machines preventing access over port 3306, or sometimes that there's simply no network connection between them. If you have command-line access to the machine running your nodejs program, try pinging the database machine. Or, try using the `mysql` command line client to connect to it.

Comment: You say you're doing this for Dialogflow. Are you using the Inline Editor in Dialogflow, Firebase Cloud Functions, or running your node.js server somewhere else? Can you update your question to clarify where you are running the node.js server or how you start it?

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

in case of a remote db i guess u need to add ur ip in the bind address of the mysql config file in the remote db. Find that file in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and restart the mysql server by 'service mysqld restart'